# Could not resolve "./components/Contact" from "src/App.jsx" The site runs locally just fine but not if I use github actions to build for auto deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-actions, hosting, build-error

It shows there is an error during the build process but nothing is wrong when I run the app locally, just trying to get a hint to figure out how to host the app with hostinger so that I can auto-delpoy and update it as I change things in the future.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Could not resolve "./components/Contact" from "src/App.jsx"
file: /home/runner/work/minimal-portfolio/minimal-portfolio/src/App.jsx
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./components/Contact" from "src/App.jsx"
    at error (file:///home/runner/work/minimal-portfolio/minimal-portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2095:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///home/runner/work/minimal-portfolio/minimal-portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23603:24)
    at file:///home/runner/work/minimal-portfolio/minimal-portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23565:26
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Github Workflow

```
name: Generate a build and push to another branch

on: 
  push:
    branches:
     - master
     
  jobs:
       build:
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         name: Build and Push
         steps:
          - name: git-checkout
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
            
          - name: Install all dependencies
            run: npm install
            
            name: build
            run: npm run build 
            
          - name: Push
            uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@develop
            env:
              REPO: self
              BRANCH: build 
              FOLDER: dist 
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
              MESSAGE: "Build: {{sha}} {msg}"
```

File Structure

```
.github/workflows
public
src
.gitignore
index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
postcss.config.cjs
tailwind.config.cjs
vite.config.js
```

Comment: Please include your repo directory structure and the relevant workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: First of all thank you for the response, I've shared the pictures in another question.  Wasn't sure how to do it here.  I'm still petty new to this.

Comment: Click "edit", and don't post pictures, post actual code.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the file structure.  Please let me know if anything else is needed for better understanding.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
The thing is in React; component names must start with a capital letter to distinguish them from regular HTML elements.

in **App.jsx** :

`import Contact from './components/Contact'`